# Can @Pattern annotation match several final String attributes, not the strings they point to?

Tags: java, regex, annotations

For example:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public class Pojo {

    public final String oneAtt = "one";
    public final String twoAtt = "two";
    public final String threeAtt = "three";

    @Pattern(regexp = <How to match any of those attributes?> )
    private String number;
```

Since the strings are defined in the attributes, the goal is to avoid repeating the strings in the pattern. So, I want to avoid this:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(one|two|three)" )
```

And looking for something like:

```
@Pattern(regexp = oneAtt|twoAtt|threeAtt )
```

Which of course it is invalid in the Java language.

The question is if there is a way to avoid duplicating the strings in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Make the three strings `static` then you can use them directly in the annotation:

```java
public static final String oneAtt = "one";
public static final String twoAtt = "two";
public static final String threeAtt = "three";

@Pattern("^(" + oneAtt + "|" + twoAtt + "|" + threeAtt + ")")
private String number;
```